# Which systems of linear equations have at least one solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Let $S$ be the set of all column matrices 
$
\begin{bmatrix}
    b_1  \\
    b_2 \\
    b_3 
  \end{bmatrix}
$
such that $b_1,b_2,b_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ and the system of equations (in real variables)
$$\begin{align*}
-x+2y+5z &=b_1 \nonumber\\
2x-4y+3z &=b_2 \nonumber\\
x-2y+2z &=b_3 
\end{align*}$$
has at least one solution.Then, which of the following system(s)(in real variables) has (have) at least one solution for each 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    b_1  \\
    b_2 \\
    b_3 
  \end{bmatrix} \in S?
$$

**A.** $x+2y+3z=b_1$, $4y+5z=b_2$ and $x+2y+6z=b_3$

**B.** $x+y+3z=b_1$, $5x+2y+6z=b_2$ and $-2x-y-3z=b_3$

**C.** $-x+2y-5z=b_1$, $2x-4y+10z=b_2$ and $x-2y+5z=b_3$

**D.** $x+2y+5z=b_1$, $2x+3z=b_2$ and $x+4y-5z=b_3$

Can anyone please help me with this problem? I am really clueless how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

For the Eq. $MX=V$ where $M$ is $3 \times 3$, $X_{3\times 1}$ is unknown vector and $V_{3 \times 1}$ is a fixed (constant). 
(1) If $V=O$ then $|M|=0$ means many solutions.

(2) If $V\ne O$

(a) then $|M|\ne 0$ means unique solution (planes meeting in a point)

(b) $|M|=0$ means many solutions (identical planes/ two identical planes one intersecting them/ planes meeting in a line)

OR no solution (parallel planes/ two identical and one parallel to them/ two parallel; and third one cutting them/ planes forming a 3D triangle or an open prism)

Here in the description $|M|=0$ and three planes are meeting in a line.

In the options $|A|\ne 0$ and $|D|\ne 0$ so there will be unique solution.

In other two options $|B|=0$. here there are no parallel or identical planes so a prism will be formed so no solution. Next |C|=0$ check there are two parallel planes (no solution).

Finally in (A) and (D) unique solution exists and it is correct option.

Answer (score 0):

For the equation $M\mathbf x=\mathbf b$ to have any solution at all, $\mathbf b$ must be an element of $M$’s column space. Thus, $S$ in your assignment is simply the column space of the matrix $$A'=\begin{bmatrix}-1&2&5\\2&-4&3\\1&-2&2\end{bmatrix}.$$ The second column is obviously a scalar multiple of the first, so $\operatorname{col}(A')$ is spanned by $\mathbf b_1 = (-1,2,1)^T$ and $\mathbf b_2 = (5,3,2)^T$.

Now, for any other matrix $A$, for the equation $A\mathbf x=\mathbf b$ to have a solution for every $\mathbf b\in S$, the column space of $A'$ must be a subset of the column space of $A$. It suffices to check that the equations $A\mathbf x=\mathbf b_1$ and $A\mathbf x=\mathbf b_2$ both have solutions. There are various ways that you might go about doing this. For instance, a systematic way is to solve both of these equations at the same time by row-reducing the matrix $\left[A\mid \mathbf b_1\,\mathbf b_2\right]$. If all of the pivots are on the left side of the reduced matrix, then both equations have solutions, and so $S\subseteq\operatorname{col}(A)$.